# Any new VBA command for font color in MS Word 365?

Tags: vba, matlab, ms-word

In my work I need to create MS Word documents using VBA in Matlab.
Currently I am facing an error when trying to set the font color in MS Word 365.

For MS Word versions 2007 and earlier I use the command

```
    color_RGB = R + 256 * G + 256 * 256 * B;  
    doc_serv.Selection.Font.Color = color_RGB;
```

While for all MS Word versions after 2007 I am using the command

```
    doc_serv.Selection.Font.TextColor.RGB = color_RGB;
```

The error message is:

```
    Error: Not implemented
```

The latter command is reporting an error when applied to MS Word 365.
Is there any new command for setting the font color again, or am I doing something wrong from the beginning?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the reported error ? Post it exactly in your post if you can. Did you try with the former again `Font.Color` ? and `Font.ColorIndex` ? Moreover, to use RGB, you can use `RGB(R,G,B)` where `R`,`G` and `B` are integers between 0 and 255.

Comment: @JeanRostan, The `RGB(R,G,B)` is not a valid command in Matlab. I didn't test the previous commands `Font.Color` because the error is reported from another site. `R`, `G` and `B` in my code are already intergers between 0 and 255. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the problem I found out that the error is not from the font command by itself. The error appears only if a popup message from MS Word 365 is blocking the progress. As an example, if the user does not sign in into an online account then a message will appear asking him to sign in. This crashed the VBA engine at different positions (assigning font color, creating a table, ..).

I hope this will help someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

According to the Word [language reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/word-vba/articles/font-textcolor-property-word?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) the property `TextColor` is read-only. If it was working before that must have been a bug...

Stick with what worked in previous versions - Font.Color - it should still work. Microsoft is usually very careful about backwards compatibility and wouldn't change such a basic property without a very good reason. And there has been nothing happening with the font display engine that would warrant any kind of change like that.